# Guake terminal can't act as gnome-terminal

Tags: linux

How can I let Guake terminal print correctly,just like in terminal?
I have found some questions in StackOverflow,and I don't konw the command about script.

this is the screenshot:
[guake terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V8ijA.png)

this is in terminal: [terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKkDi.png)

Thanks for watching and answering.

Comment: Probably you want to [change font preferences in Guake](http://askubuntu.com/a/276610/452930)? Also, I don't understand relationship between your post content and title. What has `.bashrc` to do with anything?

Comment: sorrt, I had thought it is because of.bashrc,I have change the title.

Comment: Also, I had  change font  already. However, it doesn't work.

Comment: it really change when font changed, but it looked weird.

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with the .bashrc file.
You should just go to Guake preferences and choose the font and colours you want under the `Appearance` tab.
You can check `Use the system fixed width font` to use the same font as the default terminal.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I finally understand the problem. I change the font with mono, and it work.

Comment: You're welcome :)
Please consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) if it helped.